# How to wrap long messages using Editor in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, editor

I am using Editor control and wish to wrap long messages (Like Whatsapp).
I have explored few sites and got nothing . If this feature is not yet in Xamarin Forms , can I know any alternative for the same ?

My XAML

```
<Editor Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TextMessage}" 
                            TextColor="{StaticResource StartColor}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            FontSize="14" TextChanged="Editor_TextChanged" 
                            FontFamily="{StaticResource DefaultFont}" IsEnabled="True"/>
```

OUTPUT-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, The Editor control has a property for this called the [AutoSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.editor.autosize?view=xamarin-forms) Property which takes the [EditorAutoSizeOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.editorautosizeoption?view=xamarin-forms) enum as an input. Available options are `TextChanges` and `Disabled`.

```
<Editor AutoSize="TextChanges"...
```

If for some reason this does not work for you then you can use the solution in [this forum discussion.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/92439/automatic-expandable-editor) by ionixjunior.

Comment: "Disabled" was what I needed . Thanks for help

Answer (score 3):

I would first suggest you to use `AutoSize` property of `Editor`, so if you want your editor to automatically resize depending on the text length, you should set it to `TextChanges`, otherwise set it to `Disabled`(this is default value).

Next thing, if you know that the Editor will be used for chat, you can also set `Keyboard` property to `Chat`:

```
<Editor Text="Enter text here" AutoSize="TextChanges" Keyboard="Chat" />
```

Comment: "Disabled" was what I needed . Yeah I will use Keyboard="Chat" also . Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still facing issues, I have a case where the line does not wrap as long as there is no break line (Enter). Solution was to change parent layout from `StackLayout` to `Grid`. With grid, now it works.
If you want the height to change dynamically when you have more lines, you can use the above solution:

```
AutoSize="TextChanges"
```